# Complex feature space with binary labels

Tags: machine-learning

Which machine learning technique should be employed when the feature space is  both an image, and a time series for a single label.

The label in this problem is binary.

Comment: What do you mean by an image and a time series? That sounds like a video. The fact that the output is binary is not so important. The methods that come to mind (some kind of CNN/LSTM hybrid, but also random forest, support vectors, etc) handle binary, categorical, and continuous outputs ("regression") just fine.

Comment: @Dave Please see this post

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487830/confusing-feature-space?noredirect=1#comment900871_487830

Comment: Why would you close that question @Dave I asked it again for a reason. You comment did absolutely nothing to help.

Comment: Sycorax closed the question because you've already asked it. Please edit your question if you want to clarify what you're asking.